# Create dynamic links in the navigation panel

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, tag-helpers

I am trying to dynamically create my top navigation panel in ASP.NET Core MVC 6.

I know it's simple but I cannot figure out how to make it work. Here is what I do (simplified):

My Model:

```
public class IP_Category
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
}
```

in my controller:

```
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        //This way I dynamically pass data to my View
        ViewBag.Categories = _repository.ReturnCategories();
        return View();
    }
```

in my `cshtml` page:

```
@{
    //this info is in the top of the page, here I retrieve data passed from
    //controller and save it as a local variable
    var categories = (List<IP_Category>)ViewBag.Categories;
}
```

Then later in the _Layout where I take care of the navigation:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li><a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">Home</a></li>
    <li><a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="About">About</a></li>
    <li><a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Contact">Contact</a></li>

    @foreach (var category in categories)
    {
        <li><a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="@category.DisplayName">@category.DisplayName</a></li>
    }
</ul>
```

The problem occurs with `asp-action="@category.DisplayName"` which does not generate appropriate href in my actual page.

So the question is what am I doing wrong? How can I pass `category.DisplayName` to my `asp-action` tag so the links work correctly?

**Edit 1 - Adding more code:**

Here is what was generated (note the missing href tag)

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="/Home/About">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="/Home/Contact">Contact</a></li>

    <li><a href="">Item1</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Item2</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What is it actually generating?

Comment: I have updated my post

Comment: I guess your problem is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38797393/asp-controller-and-asp-action-attributes-not-working

Comment: Nope, my tag helpers are set up correctly; if it was not working then my default elements would not as well (the first three)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the controller and action don't match an existing controller and action then no href will be rendered. I suspect that @category.DisplayName does not match any actual action name on your home controller. Seems more likely that you have an action named Category that expects a parameter corresponding to the @category.DisplayName so it should be passed as a route parameter not as the action name

```
@foreach (var category in categories)
{
    <li><a asp-controller="Home" 
               asp-action="Category" 
       asp-route-category="@category.DisplayName">@category.DisplayName</a></li>
}
```

Comment: You were right! I didn't know that if the actual `IActionResult` under my controller exist, then it would not create appropriate href. Thank you!