# Can't redirect the submit to an action

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core, tag-helpers

I have the following actions and view following [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/working-with-forms?view=aspnetcore-2.2#the-form-tag-helper).

```
[HttpPost("validate")]
public IActionResult Validate([FromQuery] string user, string pass)
{ ... }

[HttpGet("login")]
public IActionResult LogIn([FromQuery] string returnUrl)
{ 
  ...
  return View(model); 
}
```

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers;
@model Dictionary<string, string>

<form asp-controller="account" asp-action="validate" method="post">
  <input asp-for="@Model["user"]" placeholder="Username" />
  <input asp-for="@Model["pass"]" placeholder="Password" />
  <button type="submit">Go!</button>
</form>
```

Upon click on the button, I get back to the same action (i.e. *LogIn*) insteda of the specified (i.e. *Validate*). It seems like the only thing I control in the form is the method. I've added *using* statement for accessing [the library of *TagHelpers*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38797767/1525840) but it seems it doesn't do jack difference.

What can I have missed?

Comment: What does the final rendered HTML in your browser look like? Does a proper URL appear in the form’s `action` attribute? – Also, just in case, try to make the values for `asp-controller` and `asp-action` case-sensitive, i.e. `asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Validate"`. Also also, you want to remove the `[FromQuery]` from your POST action. The parameters are passed as form data, not query (you also generally don’t need those `From~` attributes unless you are doing unusual stuff.

Comment: @poke The final rendition (ctrl+u in Chrome or F12 and check for the elements) produces *<form asp-controller="account" asp-action="validate" method="post">...<button type="submit">Check the credentials</button>
</form>*. I was expecting the *asp-xxx* attributes to be transformed. Was I mistaken? (I've tried the case sensitivity with the expected outcome - no difference. Also, good point on the *FromXxx* attribute - I guess I started to feel panic and began to do trial-and-horror.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The final rendition (ctrl+u in Chrome or F12 and check for the elements) produces `<form asp-controller="account" asp-action="validate" method="post">...<button type="submit">Check the credentials</button> </form>`. I was expecting the `asp-xxx` attributes to be transformed. Was I mistaken?

No, you are correct. These tag helper attributes should have been transformed into a single `action` attribute that contains the target URL to your `Validate` action.

Since the attributes were not transformed that means that the tag helpers did not run. This is most likely caused by a missing `@addTagHelper` directive.

You need to have the following line either in your view itself, or in the `_ViewImports.cshtml` file (where the line should be by default):

```
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
```

Importing the namespace with a `@using` directive is not necessary.

Comment: So, just to verify that I get it correctly - the part *@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers;* is irrelevant in this context? I added it because I believed that it was **this one** that caused the helpers to execute. The directive you present is new to me. I guess I've been diving the Angular lake a bit too long and C# ran away from me.

Comment: The `@using` directive is used to make types in a certain namespace available from Razor code (e.g. you can do `@model Foo` instead of `@model MyApp.Models.Foo` if you have a `@using MyApp.Models` somewhere). But in order to activate tag helpers, you need the `@addTagHelper` directive.