# Getting HTTP ERROR 400 when form gets posted

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have an asp.net core razor page where I have a simple form that asks for a user email address and a submit button.  When I enter the email and click the submit button I'm always getting a 400 error

> HTTP ERROR 400

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.  I tried putting a break point right inside the OnPost method, but I'm not even getting to that point.

Below is my code:

Homie.cshtml

```
@page
@model WebApplication1.Pages.HomieModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Homie";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h1>Homie</h1>

<form method="post">
    <input type="email" name="emailaddress">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Homie.cshtml.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;

namespace WebApplication1.Pages
{
    public class HomieModel : PageModel
    {
        public void OnGet(string n)
        {
        }

        public void OnPost()
        {
            var emailAddress = Request.Form["emailaddress"];
            // do something with emailAddress
        }

    }
}
```

Error message (screen capture):
[image]

Comment: Do you see any other information in the response apart from 400?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya  no.. nothing

Comment: Are you able to debug the code of `OnPost`?  Are you seeing this error in browser? Can you share the screen capture if the error in browser?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya added the screen capture.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I found out what the issue was.
The problem was that it was missing the anti forgery token in the form.

I simply added `@Html.AntiForgeryToken();` inside of the form tag and everything is working as expected now.

**Homie.cshtml**

```
@page
@model WebApplication1.Pages.HomieModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Homie";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h1>Homie</h1>

<form method="post">
    <input type="email" name="emailaddress">
    <input type="submit">
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken();
</form>
```

It seems that when you have an asp.net core mvc application and when you add a razor page in to it and try to create a form it doesn't default to the [Form Tag Helper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/working-with-forms?view=aspnetcore-2.2) for asp.net core.

If you add this line to the Homie.cshtml page, `@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers` it will automatically make it a form tag helper.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38797393/asp-controller-and-asp-action-attributes-not-working).

So I changed my code Homie.cshtml to:

**Homie.cshtml**

```
@page
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
@model WebApplication1.Pages.HomieModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Homie";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h1>Homie</h1>

<form method="post">
    <input type="email" name="emailaddress">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: No need for the ; after the @Html.AntiForgeryToken() in the first example

Answer (score 0):

My problem was having 2 form elements on the page, one inside another. Once I removed one, it worked fine!